# how to maintain the FPS on realtime video using face_recognition methods and OpenCV?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to recognize faces in real-time video, but I am getting very low fps whenever the face_recogniser identifies a face and tries to decide who is the person.

I am working on a MacBook Pro but I want **high accuracy** so I am using the HOG model on the face recognizer. (The pre-processing is too slow with CNN on Mac and I got 12K pictures)

I have 4000 images for every person (12K pictures in total).

I am trying to play with the size of the frame but below width=250 it doesn't recognize any face anymore and if I am trying to play with a boolean flag (recognize faces only on odd frames) it's still too slow.

There is a chance I am getting the low fps because I am using a MacBook Pro to run it?
I am using:
Processor: 2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9
Memory: 32 GB 2667 MHz DDR4
Graphics: AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 4 GB, Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB

I have 2 ideas to try to solve it:

I was thinking to write an equivalent program in C++ but I can't be sure if I will get better fps so I don't know if it's worth it. (I didn't program in C++ for a very long time but if you think it will help I will try it)

Another idea is using MultiProcessing/MultiThreading (if its possible on MacBook Pro) for the next frames. (I have no experience using that with Python/C++, but it feels like it will be even slower, maybe I am wrong)?

any suggestions and examples?

Thanks!

**Edit: (For additional information)**
When I resize the frame to width=300:

when it doesn't recognize any face the time for face_locations and face_encodings is around 0.026 against 0.055 for the loop (single frame). when it recognizes at least one face the face_locations and face_encondings are around 0.05-0.03 against around 0.09 for the loop (one frame).

when detecting multiple faces the face_encodings and face_locations can increase the time by 0.06+.

any solutions?

```
# import the necessary packages
from imutils import paths
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import pickle
import cv2
import os
import time

# video path
video_path = "12-6-2021-news.mp4"

# Audio Player
    #***RIGHT NOW THE AUDIO DOESN'T STOP AND IT TOO FAST FOR THE VIDEO SO IT COMMENTED***
    
#player = MediaPlayer(video_path)
# initialize the video stream, then allow the camera sensor to warm up
print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
# frame catcher
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

# loop over frames from the video file stream
while True:
    # grab the frame from the threaded video stream
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    # convert the input frame from BGR to RGB then resize it to have
    # a width of 750px (to speedup processing)
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    rgb = imutils.resize(frame, width=250)
    r = frame.shape[1] / float(rgb.shape[1])

    # detect the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding boxes
    # corresponding to each face in the input frame, then compute
    # the facial embeddings for each face
    
    boxes = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb)
    encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb, boxes)
    names = []
    
    
    # loop over the facial embeddings
    for encoding in encodings:
        # attempt to match each face in the input image to our known
        # encodings
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(data["encodings"],
            encoding)
        name = "Unknown"

        # check to see if we have found a match
        if True in matches:
            # find the indexes of all matched faces then initialize a
            # dictionary to count the total number of times each face
            # was matched
            matchedIdxs = [i for (i, b) in enumerate(matches) if b]
            counts = {}

            # loop over the matched indexes and maintain a count for
            # each recognized face face
            for i in matchedIdxs:
                name = data["names"][i]
                counts[name] = counts.get(name, 0) + 1

            # determine the recognized face with the largest number
            # of votes (note: in the event of an unlikely tie Python
            # will select first entry in the dictionary)
            name = max(counts, key=counts.get)
            # update the list of names
        names.append(name)
    
     #loop over the recognized faces
    for ((top, right, bottom, left), name) in zip(boxes, names):
        # rescale the face coordinates
        top = int(top * r)
        right = int(right * r)
        bottom = int(bottom * r)
        left = int(left * r)

        # draw the predicted face name on the image
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom),
            (0, 255, 0), 2)
        y = top - 15 if top - 15 > 15 else top + 15
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        0.75, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    
    
    # grab the current audio frame from the video
        #***RIGHT NOW THE AUDIO DOESN'T STOP AND IT TOO FAST FOR THE VIDEO SO IT COMMENTED***

        #audio_frame, val = player.get_frame()

    if cv2.waitKey(15) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break
    
    #***RIGHT NOW THE AUDIO DOESN'T STOP AND IT TOO FAST FOR THE VIDEO SO IT COMMENTED***
        #if val != 'eof' and audio_frame is not None:
                # play audio
            #img, t = audio_frame

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

            
# do a bit of cleanup
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.waitKey(1)
cap.release()
print("[INFO] WELL DONE!")
```

Comment: Have you timed each step? How long does it take to run `face_locations` and `face_encodings` vs. the rest of the code?

Comment: Did you check what language the `cv2` library is written in?

Comment: @Berriel Using resizes frame with width=300: when it doesn't recognize any face the time for face_locations and face_encodings is around 0.026 against 0.055 for the loop for one frame. when it recognizes at least one face the face_locations and face_encondings are around 0.05-0.04 against 0.09 for the loop (one frame).

Comment: @KlausD. C++ of course.  but I meant using C++ to get better performance with the "for loops" and the other code (not OpenCV functions). but right now as you can see, the face_locations and face_encodings are increasing the time by 0.03-0.04 when detecting a face.

Comment: @RoyAmoial Do these timings consider the time to read the frame (i.e., `cap.read()`) and the 15ms you added on the `waitKey`? Are you also considering the `imshow`? What is your goal? 30FPS?

Comment: @Berriel These timings consider the times of imshow, cap. read() and the waitKey(15) but now I changed it to waitKey(1). I get 22-23 FPS when it doesn't recognize any face, 13-12 FPS when it recognizes a single face, and 9 FPS when it recognizes 2 faces, and so on.. Any idea how to improve it? Achieving around 30 fps when recognizing multiple faces with higher width (400-500) would be great!

Comment: Is there any progress? @RoyAmoyal I am running into the same problem, I would like to run my program on a raspberry, but currently the program runs very slow even on my laptop, so I am trying to improve the performance as well. Did you find any performance improvement? :)